# Can't get the right CPUcore temperature (Acpi chip)

Tags: 14.04, temperature, acpi

After replacing my motherboard I try to get `Psensor` working correctly but still I cannot get the right temperature for my CPUcore temp, it's always -127C degrees. I installed `lm-sensors` and everything it's needed to check the temp, so after running:

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

I answered `yes` to everything and it found:

```
Driver `f71882fg':
* ISA bus, address 0x295
Chip `Fintek F71882FG/F71883FG Super IO Sensors' (confidence: 9)
```

I ran:

```
sudo service kmod start
```

when I do:

```
sudo modprobe f71882fg
```

I get:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'f71882fg': Device or resource busy
```

the output of `dmesg | tail` says:

```
[47593.565779] f71882fg: Found f71882fg chip at 0x290, revision 32
[47593.565857] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x00000290-0x00000297 conflicts with OpRegion 0x00000295-0x00000296 (\IP__) (20140424/utaddress-258)
[47593.565870] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
```

What would be my further actions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Oli says, you only need the `coretemp` module to read Intel CPU core temperature.

I have a similar problem with my `w83667hg` hardware monitor driver. The workaround is to add `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` to the kernel command line. To that end

1. edit `/etc/default/grub` and insert `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` into the parameter string of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`, e. g.

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX='acpi_enforce_resources=lax'
   ```
2. then run `update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: Danke! Thanks a lot finally I got something to work now it shows temp and fan rpm etc just using `sensors` in terminal. Also is it possible or it's not recommended to take off/remove this virtual adapter value http://i.imgur.com/ubtlKmv.png?1 because it's even shown in Psensor still. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Purely by observation I'd simply ignore the `acpitz-virtual-0` module, because it obviously produces bogus values. I remember that you can tell `sensors-detect` to ignore and not display the data from a particular module.

Comment: As also mentioned in other websites, it seems that adding acpi_enforce_resources=lax works, but I have a problem and I can't reboot my PC. Is there any answer without the need to reboot?

Comment: @mohammadhmontazeri: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. I can take a look at it if you send me a link to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd skip `lm-sensors` and just read from `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp`. This should be automatically registered for an ACPI chip. [The unit is millidegrees Celsius](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/thermal/sysfs-api.txt).

```
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp 
47000
```

There may be many `thermal_zoneN` devices. In my experience, the CPU is usually the first (and one for each core) but I'm not sure I'd depend on that always being the case.

For other devices that aren't registered through the thermal sysfs API, you would need `lm-sensors` or something similar.

Comment: it works but it says `-127000` anyways, that's the problem.

Comment: Liquid nitrogen cooling? :D

Comment: it's simply stock intel.