# pwm-config detects fan but doesn't influence it at all

Tags: hp, overheating, fan, temperature, lm-sensors

I have a HP Pavilion Power Desktop and recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS alongside Windows 10. So far so good, except that when I boot ubuntu, my fan  (I have only one fan) immediately revs up to full speed, despite the fact that there are no resource intensive processes running. I installed lm-sensors and the temperatures of my cores are around 30-40 degrees celsius, which isn't a temperature that warrants the fan running all the time. I do not have this problem when running on Windows 10, so I figure, that ubuntu is missing a decent way to control the fans.

I first checked whether there were any options in the BIOS, but there are none regarding the fan. (None, which I found at least).

So I installed lm-sensors and had it detect my hardware, but all it added to etc/modules was a signle line "coretemp", which as of my understanding is just the module for my main CPU cores. It DOES however detect my fan and shows me with how much RPM it is running.

[First picture: sensors output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGTKA.png)

As you can see the fan is running at approx. 2000 RPM at all times.

I tried to run pwm-config, and it also detects my fan under hwmon1 succesfully (You can see in the first picture, that my fan is running under "nouveau-pci-0100" and in the second picture you can see that "nouveau" is associated to hwmon1). But then, when it tries to speed it down, it doesn't work.

[Second picture: pwmconfig output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svMq5.png)

The output sais, that there was no correlation between the pwm output and the resulting speed. Is there a configuration, that I did wrong? Or does my fan not support pwm at all? If that's the case, are there any other options to control my fan speed manually or preventing them from running at full speed all the time?

Comment: The nouveau fan is your video card fan.  Run `sensors-detect`, when it checks for Super I/O chips, see if it finds anything.

Comment: @rtaft Thanks for your response! I had sensors-detect run twice now, and both times I replied "yes" to every single option and coretemp was the only thing, that was added.

Comment: @rtaft I'm not quite sure what you mean by "Super I/O chips". Could you elaborate? And how would I spot them in sensors-detect?

Comment: Look at this example https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158048/fan-control-with-nct6796d-on-asrock-j5005-itx-cant-load-nct6775-module  at the Super I/O section, it has a 'Yes' without a 'Success!' as well as `Found unknown chip with ID 0xd423`.  Also have you updated your acpi settings in grub?  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/591198/cant-get-the-right-cpucore-temperature-acpi-chip

Comment: @rtaft I added the line ´GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX='acpi_enforce_resources=lax'´ to etc/default/grub and updated it. I then tried to look at what sensors-detect finds underthe Super I/O cjips section. I just realized tht at the start section, I get a bunch of "Operation not permitted messages"...

https://imgur.com/a/xbHnB9k

Comment: Are you using secure boot?  That may block access to /dev/port

Comment: @rtaft No, I'm not. But it looks like this is a lead on the problem, right?

Comment: @imu011 Yes, focus on why you can't scan the hardware, I can't offer much more besides searching the internet for possible answers at this point.

Comment: you could also try undoing the grub changes and see if that broke it.

Comment: @rtaft It turns out - call me stupid - that I was using secure boot after all. I didn't know that was a default setting. However, I deactivated it and now I run into the scenario from the example you posted: A "Yes" without success and an "Unknown Chip" in the Super I/O section

https://imgur.com/a/pYfBZCK

sensors-detect still only finds "coretemp" and pwmconfig doesn't stop the fan at all.

Comment: @imu011 The issue is that it does not know what 0x8528 is.  I haven't had much luck finding any posts that got it working.  Given the fact that the source code for sensors-detect has ALL of the 0x85 series as 'to-be-written' seems to indicate that no one has written a driver for this yet.

Comment: @rtaft Alright, thanks. Looks like I have to find another solution or just live with it. Thanks you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been almost three years since I posted this, turns out I just forgot to install my NVIDIA drivers